# Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor when there is no constructor call at all

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to write unit tests for the code provided in http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=fibonacci-heap

I am stuck in the first line though. My test looks like this:

```
public class fibonacciHeapTest {


    fibonacciHeap<Integer> fibHeap= new fibonacciHeap<>();

    @Test(expected = HeapEmptyException.class)
    public void testGetMin() throws HeapEmptyException {

        System.assert(true, fibHeap.isEmpty()); // Here I get the error mentioned in the title.

    }
```

Also the same line when looked at System, gives the following message int he dropdown : System cannot be resolved into a variable.

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: Use org.junit.Assert, instead of System.assert

Comment: Also, respect the Java naming conventions. Classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @Jens that does not work either. I have the following error : org.junit cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @JBNizet I will look into Java conventions. Thank you.

Comment: You have to add junit as a dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets give some more precise feedback to get you going:

public class FibonacciHeapTest { // as mentioned, UpperCase!

Your first test could be:

```
@Test 
public void testIsEmptyOnNewHeap() {
  assertThat(new FibonnacciHeap<String>().isEmpty(), is(true));
}
```

The point is: isEmpty() should obviously **not** throw an exception, so you dont want the "expected" statement. Please note: I turned to **assertThat** and the hamcrest **is** matcher - don't waste your time learning about other asserts. assertThat is the only assert you will ever need. (but it takes a bit of reading to learn about it)

Then:

```
@Test(expected=HeapEmptyException.class) 
public void testGetOnEmptyHeap() {
   new FibonacciHeap<String>().pop();
}
```

The point here: your heap has a method to get values, I called it "pop()". And obviously - when you pop something from an empty stack, you should see an exception.

These are some examples how you write unit tests. You do **one** thing in your test; and you check one thing; either using asserts, or by expecting exceptions.

Comment: I was referring to https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests. I am confused if my unit test should do just one thing, or test all cases of one method. I will appreciate a clarification

Comment: One **test** method should test one specific functionality. "Functionalities" would be: pop something from an empty heap. put one thing in, and check that pop returns the thing you put in. And so on. So, yes, sometimes your test method calls several of your production methods. So the idea is that there is **minimal** overlap between your test methods. Although in practice, that is not always possible.